# Showing all li with a certain value and hide all others using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is one of the many li elemnts I have in my ul:

```
<li data-content="51046" data-state="1" data-qty="1">
    <span data-action="newspaper-date">04.01.1980</span>
</li>
```

As you can see, it has a date in the HTML content. Now I also have an input filed where a date in the form of dd.mm.yyyy is entered. The input is stored in a variable called `inputValue`, its refreshed everytime a change happens in the input field.

I tried to show the li elemnts with this code:

```
$j('.dropdown ul li:contains("' + inputValue + '")').show();
```

That works, but it does not hide the ones not matching. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here working code:

```js
let inputValue = "04.01.1980"

$('ul li span').each(function(ix, el) {
  console.log($(this).html())
  if ($(this).html() == inputValue)
    $(this).closest("li").toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-content="51046" data-state="1" data-qty="1" style="display:none">
    <span data-action="newspaper-date">04.01.1980</span>
  </li>
  <li data-content="51046" data-state="1" data-qty="1" style="display:none">
    <span data-action="newspaper-date">05.01.1980</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```